# Progress listener passed through classes

Tags: java, progress-bar, listener, progress

I have a class (SearchIndexManager) which does calculations:

```
public void buildSearchIndex(SwiftDocList docList, TagManager tm)
{
        System.out.println("Building index...");

        // for indexing progress
        int nCounter = 0;
        for (SwiftDoc doc : docList)
        {
            // create a lucene doc to add to the index
            Document luceneDoc = makeLuceneDocument(doc);

            // ready to add the document
            indexer.addDocument(luceneDoc);

            // Some calculations

            // progress ( Thats how I measure progress)
            int nProgress = (int) (99 * ((double) ++nCounter / docList.size()));
        }
        // close the index
        indexer.close();
    }
```

I have another class which calls the above class.

```
mSearchManager = new SearchIndexManager();
mSearchManager.buildSearchIndex(mAllDocs, mTagBrowserModel.getTagManager());
```

Then I have a GUI class, which calls above class and invokes the method of the first class, which does some calculations. I need to show the progress of these long calculations on GUI. How can I do that using some listeners.

Comment: Swing? JavaFX? ... ?

Comment: GUI is in SWING